# After a Windows 8 update I don't get my boot menu anymore

Tags: grub2, windows, boot-repair

I did a software update on my 64-bit Windows 8 and after restarting my computer, I no longer get my boot menu with Ubuntu 12.10, but instead get a black screen that says:

error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>

This is after running boot-repair, which gave me this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1369161

I really have no idea what to do. Thank you in advance for any response!

Comment: have you tried changing the boot flag to your ubuntu partition? you can do that through a live CD using gparted, select the linux partition, right click then "manage flags" and check the boot flag.

Comment: didn't work. The windows partition has a red (!) next to it when I looked at its information, it says

cluster accounting failed at (0x4d13e2): extra cluster in $Bitmap. It is the same error two more times for (0x4d13e3) and (0x4d13e4). It says ERROR: NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on windows then reboot twice. I can't even boot into Windows...

Comment: Don't move the boot flag, it is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Windows disk this way: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader , until you get direct access to Windows
2. Then use Boot-Repair to recover your GRUB menu.